# Ошибка при добавлении пользователя в БД при помощи POST запроса из модального окна

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post

Добрый вечер. Создаю телефонный справочник для организации с возможностью добавления и удаления контактов. Полный код можно найти на GIT(https://github.com/Vankalif/pbook). История следующая, логинюсь в админ панель и добавляю пользователя
[image: пример добавление пользователя]

Все хорошо, пользователь в БД(MySQL) добавляется, отрабатывает JS код

```
$("#add_user").click(function() {

var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var profession = document.getElementById("profession").value;
var cabinet = document.getElementById("cabinet").value;
var department = document.getElementById("department").value;
var location = document.getElementById("location").value;

$.post(
    "adminTools.php", {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        profession: profession,
        cabinet: cabinet,
        department: department,
        location: location
    },
    onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == "400") {
        $("#add_answer").html("Ошибка создания");
    } else if (data == "200") {
        $("#add_answer").html("Пользователь успешно создан");
    }
}
```

});

в обработчике adminTools.php, в свою очередь есть проверка на дублирование данных

```
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/db.php';

function compareStr (string $param, string $param2){
    $param = mb_strtolower($param);
    $param2 = mb_strtolower($param2);

    $retVal = ($param === $param2) ? true : false ;

    return $retVal;
}

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['profession'], $_POST['cabinet'], $_POST['department'], $_POST['location'])){

    // ищем пользователя в БД
    $user = R::findOne('data', 'name = ?', array($_POST['name']));

    // Если нашли, то сравниваем все поля, если есть разные записываем,
    //иначе завершаем работу скрипта
    if($user){


        if(compareStr($user->name, $_POST['name']) && 
            compareStr($user->phone, $_POST['phone']) && 
            compareStr($user->profession, $_POST['profession']) &&
            compareStr($user->cabinet, $_POST['cabinet']) &&
            compareStr($user->department, $_POST['department']) &&
            compareStr($user->location, $_POST['location'])
            ){
                die("400");
            }
    }


    $data = R::dispense('data');

        $data->name = $_POST['name'];
        $data->phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $data->profession = $_POST['profession'];
        $data->cabinet = $_POST['cabinet'];
        $data->department = $_POST['department'];
        $data->location = $_POST['location'];

        R::store($data);

        die("200");


        }
```

если ввести одинаковые данные, то пользователь не создастся, но тут именно кроется ошибка, пока открыто окно, пока не перезагрузил страницу и нажимаешь на кнопку он записывает одинаковых пользователей в БД. При дебаге, видно что эта функция библиотеки RedBean PHP:

```
$user = R::findOne('data', 'name = ?', array($_POST['name']));
```

не видит, что в БД уже создался пользователь. Если перезагрузить страницу и ввести то же самое, то блокировка отлично отработает. Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит.

PS в разработке новичок.

Comment: А что Вам мешает Вам при отправке данных аяксом получать всех пользователей и делать проверку? То есть тоже самое, что Вы делаете после обновления страницы?

Comment: @DaemonHK вы имеете ввиду выполнять проверку на стороне клиента, при помощи JavaScript?

Comment: да, отправили данные, получили общий список, проверили на наличие, обычно вроде так делается, или, судя по коду, проверять каждое поле на уникальность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

хз что за библиотека ))) скорее всего изменения не вступают в силу иза не закрытия соединения , попробуйте закрыть банальным R::close (может прокатит)))))) или поищите в доке альтернативные решение .
Я бы на вашем месте удалил всю никчемную библиотеку и вписал свой код. Могу помочь если надо.
Как альтернативное решение , можно добавить перезагрузку страницы.

```
<scrip>
$(document).ready(function(){
var myflag = 0;
$("#add_user").click(function() {
if(myflag > 0)return false;
myflag++;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var profession = document.getElementById("profession").value;
var cabinet = document.getElementById("cabinet").value;
var department = document.getElementById("department").value;
var location = document.getElementById("location").value;

$.post(
    "adminTools.php", {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        profession: profession,
        cabinet: cabinet,
        department: department,
        location: location
    },
    onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == "400") {
        $("#add_answer").html("Ошибка создания");
        myflag--;
    } else if (data == "200") {
        alert("Пользователь успешно создан");
         window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }
}
});
});
</scrip>
```

Comment: Получается при добавлении каждого пользователя будет перезагружаться страница? Мне кажется, не самое хорошее решение.

Comment: Действительно закрытие соединения помогло. Спасибо, просто так и не понял почему так получалось.